# Store image upload in folder = to session id?

Tags: php, image, session, upload

i have a script that uploads photos to a directory 'file/'.
I am wanting to make it so that within the 'file' directory there is another folder which is labelled the session id of the user logged in. so if user '1' uploads the photo it will go to 'file/1/default.jpg' and if user '2' 'file/2/default.jpg'.

Can anyone please tell me how i might go about doing this. thanks.

html:

```
<input type="file" class="droparea spot" name="xfile" data-post="upload.php" data-width="180" data-height="250" data-crop="true"/>


                <form id="sampleform" action="post.php" method="post">

                </form>
                <script>
                    $('#sampleform').submit(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $.ajax({
                            url:$(this).attr('action'),
                            type:'post',
                            data:$(this).serialize(),
                            dataType:'json',
                            success:function(r){
                                $('#form-result').append(
                                '<div><b>Title: </b>'+r.title+'</div>'
                                ,'<div><b>Description: </b>'+r.description+'</div>'
                                ,'<div><b>Image/File: </b>'
                                  +'<a href="'+ r.url +'" target="_blank">'+ r.url +'</a>'
                                  +'</div>'
                                );
                            }
                        });
                });
                </script>
            </div>

            <script>
            // Calling jQuery "droparea" plugin
            $('.droparea').droparea({
                'init' : function(result){
                    //console.log('custom init',result);
                },
                'start' : function(area){
                    area.find('.error').remove(); 
                },
                'error' : function(result, input, area){
                    $('<div class="error">').html(result.error).prependTo(area); 
                    return 0;
                    //console.log('custom error',result.error);
                },
                'complete' : function(result, file, input, area){
                    if((/image/i).test(file.type)){
                        area.find('img').remove();
                        //area.data('value',result.filename);
                        area.append($('<img>',{'src': result.path + result.filename + '?' + Math.random()}));
                    } 
                    //console.log('custom complete',result);
                }
            });
            </script>
```

upload.php:

```
<?php

// LOG
$log = '=== ' . @date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ===============================' . "\n"
        . 'FILES:' . print_r($_FILES, 1) . "\n"
        . 'POST:' . print_r($_POST, 1) . "\n";
$fp = fopen('upload-log.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $log);
fclose($fp);


// Result object
$r = new stdClass();
// Result content type
header('content-type: application/json');


// Maximum file size
$maxsize = 10; //Mb
// File size control
if ($_FILES['xfile']['size'] > ($maxsize * 1048576)) {
    $r->error = "Max file size: $maxsize Kb";
}


// Uploading folder
$folder = 'files/';
if (!is_dir($folder))
    mkdir($folder);
// If specifics folder 
$folder .= $_POST['folder'] ? $_POST['folder'] . '/' : '';
if (!is_dir($folder))
    mkdir($folder);


// If the file is an image
if (preg_match('/image/i', $_FILES['xfile']['type'])) {

    $filename = $_POST['value'] ? $_POST['value'] :
            $folder . '_default.jpg';
} else {

    $tld = split(',', $_FILES['xfile']['name']);
    $tld = $tld[count($tld) - 1];
    $filename = $_POST['value'] ? $_POST['value'] :
            $folder . '_default.jpg';
}


// Supporting image file types
$types = Array('image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg');
// File type control
if (in_array($_FILES['xfile']['type'], $types)) {
    // Create an unique file name    
    // Uploaded file source
    $source = file_get_contents($_FILES["xfile"]["tmp_name"]);
    // Image resize
    imageresize($source, $filename, $_POST['width'], $_POST['height'], $_POST['crop'], $_POST['quality']);
} else
// If the file is not an image
if (in_array($_FILES['xfile']['type'], $types)) 
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["xfile"]["tmp_name"], $filename);



// File path
$path = str_replace('upload.php', '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

// Result data
$r->filename = $filename;
$r->path = $path;
$r->img = '<img src="' . $path . $filename . '" alt="image" />';

// Return to JSON
echo json_encode($r);

// Image resize function with php + gd2 lib
function imageresize($source, $destination, $width = 0, $height = 0, $crop = false, $quality = 80) {
    $quality = $quality ? $quality : 80;
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($source);
    if ($image) {
        // Get dimensions
        $w = imagesx($image);
        $h = imagesy($image);
        if (($width && $w > $width) || ($height && $h > $height)) {
            $ratio = $w / $h;
            if (($ratio >= 1 || $height == 0) && $width && !$crop) {
                $new_height = $width / $ratio;
                $new_width = $width;
            } elseif ($crop && $ratio <= ($width / $height)) {
                $new_height = $width / $ratio;
                $new_width = $width;
            } else {
                $new_width = $height * $ratio;
                $new_height = $height;
            }
        } else {
            $new_width = $w;
            $new_height = $h;
        }
        $x_mid = $new_width * .5;  //horizontal middle
        $y_mid = $new_height * .5; //vertical middle
        // Resample
        error_log('height: ' . $new_height . ' - width: ' . $new_width);
        $new = imagecreatetruecolor(round($new_width), round($new_height));
        imagecopyresampled($new, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $w, $h);
        // Crop
        if ($crop) {
            $crop = imagecreatetruecolor($width ? $width : $new_width, $height ? $height : $new_height);
            imagecopyresampled($crop, $new, 0, 0, ($x_mid - ($width * .5)), 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
            //($y_mid - ($height * .5))
        }
        // Output
        // Enable interlancing [for progressive JPEG]
        imageinterlace($crop ? $crop : $new, true);

        $dext = strtolower(pathinfo($destination, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if ($dext == '') {
            $dext = $ext;
            $destination .= '.' . $ext;
        }
        switch ($dext) {
            case 'jpeg':
            case 'jpg':
                imagejpeg($crop ? $crop : $new, $destination, $quality);
                break;
            case 'png':
                $pngQuality = ($quality - 100) / 11.111111;
                $pngQuality = round(abs($pngQuality));
                imagepng($crop ? $crop : $new, $destination, $pngQuality);
                break;
            case 'gif':
                imagegif($crop ? $crop : $new, $destination);
                break;
        }
        @imagedestroy($image);
        @imagedestroy($new);
        @imagedestroy($crop);
    }
}

?>
```

post.php:

```
<?php

// LOG
$log = '=== ' . @date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ===============================' . "\n"
        . 'FILES:' . print_r($_FILES, 1) . "\n"
        . 'POST:' . print_r($_POST, 1) . "\n";
$fp = fopen('post-log.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $log);
fclose($fp);


// Result object
$r = new stdClass();
// Result content type
header('content-type: application/json');


$data = $_POST['thumbnail'];
unset($_POST['thumbnail']);

if($data){

    // Uploading folder
    $folder = 'files/';
    if (!is_dir($folder))
        mkdir($folder);
    // If specifics folder 
    $folder .= $_POST['folder'] ? $_POST['folder'] . '/' : '';
    if (!is_dir($folder))
        mkdir($folder);


    $filename = $_POST['value'] ? $_POST['value'] :
            $folder . sha1(@microtime() . '-' . $_POST['name']) . '.jpg';


    $data = split(',', $data);
    file_put_contents($filename, base64_decode($data[1]));

}
die(json_encode(array_merge(array('url' => $filename), $_POST)));

?>
```

Comment: `@date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` -- seriously? o_O

Answer (score 1):

```
// Uploading folder
$folder = 'files/';
if (!is_dir($folder))
    mkdir($folder);

// If specifics folder 
$folder .= $_POST['folder'] ? $_POST['folder'] . '/' : '';
if (!is_dir($folder))
    mkdir($folder);

// PASS USER_ID HERE
$folder2 = $_SESSION['user_id'] . '/';
if (!is_dir($folder2))
    mkdir($folder2);

// New directory with 'files/USER_SESSION_ID/'
$newDir = $folder . $folder2;
```

filename should be:

```
$filename = $_POST['value'] ? $_POST['value'] :
        $newDir . '_default.jpg';
```

```
// Uploading folder
$folder = 'files/'.$_SESSION['user_id'];
if (!is_dir($folder))
    mkdir($folder);


// If the file is an image
if (preg_match('/image/i', $_FILES['xfile']['type'])) {
    // $_FILES['xfile']['name'] .'_default.jpg' /* prevent the conflict with the same name */
    $filename = $folder . '/'. $_FILES['xfile']['name'] .'_default.jpg';
} else {

    $tld = split(',', $_FILES['xfile']['name']);
    $tld = $tld[count($tld) - 1];
    $filename = $folder . '/'. $_FILES['xfile']['name'] .'_default.jpg';
}
```

**EDIT:** i didn't found `session_start()` in your `upload.php` if you have user's session_id variable stored in your sessions then use `session_start()` in the top of the file.

Comment: thanks but that doesn't change anything. the image is still being uploaded to 'files/' and no directory with the session id is being created.

Comment: can you show the HTML part as well, to make sure about the POST values.

Comment: where is `$_POST['value'], $_POST['folder']` in your HTML part?? means your `value, folder`??

Comment: i'm not too sure why it uses those values.

Comment: i put session_start() in the top of my upload.php file and it now creates a folder with the session id but it places it outside of 'files/' and the image is still being stored in 'files/'

Comment: take a look on the following link with modified code : http://scrp.at/bZk and if you want to know about the `$_FILES, $_POST` then there is a file in your directories named `upload-log.txt` which has the log details ..